# Putting a Hash in a form in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash

I've been trying this for the last couple hours with no success.
I have one variable that holds hashes and one that holds an array of strings.
So:

```
@object.values is a Hash
@marks = Mark.all
```

If I do

```
@marks.each do |data|
  puts data.name
end
```

The output will be the strings "data1", "data2" and so on.

I wanted to make a form to assign a value to @object.values["data1"], @object.values["data2"] and so on, but when I make the form:

```
<%= form_for(@object) do |f| %>
  <% @marks.each do |data| %>

      <%= f.label data.name %>
      <%= f.text_field "values[" + data.name + "]", @object.values[data.name]%>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

I get this error:

"wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)

If I remove the "@object.values[data.name]" I get this error:

"undefined method `' for #Object:0x007fa04e2b8108>"

I've tried a few variations and some other ways to do it following some similar questions here, but all without success... I really can't figure out the correct way to do this.

Comment: take a look at nested forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: I definitely will. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. You probably want to use `fields_for`

```
<%= form_for(@object) do |f| %>
   <%= fields_for :values do |vf| %>
      <% @marks.each do |data| %>
         <%= vf.label data.name %>
         <%= vf.text_field data.name, value: @object.values[data.name]%>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```